Multiple configuration for meilisearch in Laravel Scout
I have Laravel installation with scout and mailisearch and it's work fine. In this case mailisearchis use as search engine for orders (Order model).
But now I would like add saving logs into another instance of meilisearch server.
So I make migration for logs table, make model and here I stuck... because I would like use for Log model scout with driver 'meilisearch' (like in Order model) but with different configuration - differetn host, key, index-settings.
Is it possible to have different configuration for same driver per model?
Of course I know I can change driver per model but driver will be the same I need change configuration per model.
